# Equation references not found

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I'm writing up some work and having trouble with equation numbers; the references `\ref{}` and `\eqref{}` aren't finding the references, even after multiple compiles.

`LaTeX Warning: Reference "triangle" on page 5 undefined on input line 116.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-.75in} \addtolength{\textheight}{2.00in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.00in} \addtolength{\textwidth}{.75in}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb }
\usepackage{color,graphicx, array}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[rflt]{/Users/jgates/desktop/latex/floatflt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}


\nofiles

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\begin{equation}\label{triangle}\dfrac{\Theta}{2} = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{s}    {2r_0}\right)\end{equation}

Use the geometric interpretation of \eqref{triangle}:
```

The result:

> Use the geometric interpretation of (??):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete

```
\nofiles
```

from your code. Otherwise, the information for the cross-references (among other information) will never get retrieved from the `.aux` file.

As a side note, instead of

```
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.75in} \addtolength{\textheight}{2.00in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.00in} \addtolength{\textwidth}{.75in}
```

use the `geometry` package, which you are already loading, to change the page layout.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I wonder what will screw up since I added that line for some reason at some point.... :)